# Easiest way to load model in three.js?

Tags: javascript, json, three.js

I'm very new to three.js and need some guidelines to get started.

So I have made a model with Blender, exported it to json -model and so far so good. But can someone provide a super simplified "copypaste" snippet so i can get forward?

I tried the tutorial @ http://graphic-sim.com/01_load_model.php but i just got confused and the model looks wrong in every aspect. Prt scr @ http://eljuko.com/problem_with_imports

That model should look like a cone with hole inside, not a star-edged-tube.

Thanks, Jukka Korhonen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested, a super-simple example:

http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Model.html

( ...and many more introductory examples at http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/ )

Hope this helps!